# Is WebClient.Builder.codecs() ignored in Spring Boot 2.7.*?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I use pretty straightforward configuration of my `WebClient`:

```java
@Configuration
class Config {

    @Value("${client.baseUrl}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .codecs(this::configureCodec)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    private void configureCodec(ClientCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .defaultCodecs()
                .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

And it works for `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.7`. However as of `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.8` for huge payloads I get `DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144` which is in turn fixed by adding this line to `application.properties`:

```
spring.codec.max-in-memory-size=16777216
```

Neither `ClientCodecConfigurer`, nor `WebClient.Builder.codecs()` are deprecated and their JavaDoc as of `2.7.8` says nothing about `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size` so my question is whether it is a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: On the client-side, `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size` property should not matter here. it only applies to the auto-configured `WebClient.Builder` which you're not using when defining your `webClient` bean. It may still be affecting the size of the buffers on the server-side, but I can't tell if that's relevant from what you've described thus far. Please update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve).