# Migration from Flux.flatMap() to Flux.map() breaks execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm starting to integrate Spring WebFlux into our project and have recently run into an issue regarding `Flux.flatMap()`. The following code summarizes it:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Client {

    private final ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ResponseDto>> TYPE = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
    };

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public Mono<List<ResponseDto>> queryData(List<RequestDto> request) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/api/query-data")
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(TYPE);
    }
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class DemoApplicationTest {
    static final int COUNT = 1000_000;

    @Autowired
    private Client client;


    @Test
    void requestsAreSent() {
        List<RequestDto> requests = getRequests();
        List<List<RequestDto>> partition = Lists.partition(requests, 1000);
        Flux.fromIterable(partition)
                .flatMap(client::queryData)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }

    @Test
    void requestsAreNotSent() {
        List<RequestDto> requests = getRequests();
        List<List<RequestDto>> partition = Lists.partition(requests, 1000);
        Flux.fromIterable(partition)
                .map(client::queryData)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }

    private static List<RequestDto> getRequests() {
        return IntStream.range(0, COUNT)
                .boxed()
                .map(operand -> RequestDto.builder().build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If I use `Flux.flatMap()` I see that my test sends requests to webserver, but if instead I use `Flux.map()` no request are sent.

Could one explain this behavior? Is it something inherent or I misconfigured anything?

Comment: Why are you replacing flatMap with map ? Your queryData() method returns a publisher (Mono). `map` is not adapted to this. With map, you create a Flux that contains assembled publishers. Assembling a publisher does not execute it. To execute it, you must subscribe to it. That's what flatMap (or concatMap) are designed for.

Comment: So easy explained, in this case `flatMap` returns a `Mono<T>` while the  `map` function will return a `Mono<Mono<T>>` and the `block` will only unwrap one mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive publishers like `Mono` and `Flux` are lazy. This means that they're not executed unless you subscribe to them. In both your `requestsAreSent()` and `requestsAreNotSent()` methods, you're only **subscribing to the outer publisher** by using the `block()` method.

The reason why your requests are sent within the `requestsAreSent()` method is because you use `flatMap()`. This operation flattens the inner publisher from `client.queryData()` into the outer publisher. This means that if you subscribe to the outer observable, you're also subscribed to the inner observables.

In your `requestsAreNotSent()` method on the other hand, the publishers aren't flattened, and because you only subscribe to the outer observable, the logic within `client.queryData()` isn't executed.

For example, if you subscribe to all those inner observables, the logic will be executed:

```java
List<Mono<List<ResponseDto>>> list = Flux.fromIterable(partition)
    .map(client::queryData)
    .collectList()
    .block();
list.forEach(Mono::block); // Subscribing to the inner observables
```

However, this is a bad practice and you should keep using `flatMap()`.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your comprehensive response! Not subscribing to inner observables makes sense. Could you also have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445977/is-webclient-builder-codecs-ignored-in-spring-boot-2-7?